# HTML5 Canvas diagonal lines get thicker or bolder after drawing another line somewhere else on the canvas (not on top)

Tags: javascript, typescript, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas

For horizontal and vertical lines, using translation of 0.5 for odd stroke widths produces crisper/sharper lines. How about the diagonal lines?

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4abhknwu/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body style="background: black">
    <button id="btn">Draw Next Line</button>
    <br> 
    <canvas style="border: 2px solid red" id="cnv"></canvas>
    <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById("cnv").getContext("2d");

        debugger;

        const delta = 25;
        const color = 'white';

        const W = window.innerWidth - 80;
        const H = window.innerHeight - 100;
        ctx.canvas.width = W;
        ctx.canvas.height = H;

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;

        // diagonal line.
        ctx.moveTo(0.5, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(W, H);


        ctx.stroke();
        
        // vertical lines
        let i = 0.5;
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => {
            ctx.moveTo(i * delta, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(i * delta, H);
            ctx.stroke();
            i++;
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As can be seen on the demo, after adding another line previously drawn diagonal lines get bolder or thicker.
How to get consistent thickness/sharpness irrespective of whether the diagonal line is drawn first or last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `ctx.beginPath();` call before each new line:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body style="background: black">
    <button id="btn">Draw Next Line</button>
    <br> 
    <canvas style="border: 2px solid red" id="cnv"></canvas>
    <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById("cnv").getContext("2d");

        debugger;

        const delta = 25;
        const color = 'white';

        const W = window.innerWidth - 80;
        const H = window.innerHeight - 100;
        ctx.canvas.width = W;
        ctx.canvas.height = H;

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;

        // diagonal line.
        ctx.moveTo(0.5, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(W, H);


        ctx.stroke();
        
        // vertical lines
        let i = 0.5;
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => {
            ctx.beginPath(); // <------------------------ Here
            ctx.moveTo(i * delta, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(i * delta, H);
            ctx.stroke();
            i++;
        }


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The best is actually to move the call to `.stroke()` out of the loop.

Comment: How would that look and why is it the best?

Comment: The "click" event OP uses is certainly just a debug mockup to show that the lines become less smooth based on when they were drawn. In their real case they probably do draw everything in a single go, with the same results. In that case, instead of calling `beginPath()` and `stroke()` for every line, they'd be better composing a single big subpath with all the lines and `stroke()` it only once. That's better because the engine has only one drawing operation to perform, so it's faster.

Comment: If they really were in a case where they'd want to draw each line one after another, composing one big path + clear the whole canvas would still probably be a better option, more scalable with other drawings and allowing line joins etc.

Comment: Oh yeah, if this were a single drawing without a doubt one `beginPath` and one `stroke` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would research a bit and draw a line manually using pixels and some online algorithm. This also involves special pixel function because we don't want the same effect over each pixel.
Found this function `draw_line` taken from [here](https://jstutorial.medium.com/how-to-code-your-first-algorithm-draw-a-line-ca121f9a1395)
.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

var r = 255
var g = 255
var b = 255

function pixel(x, y) {
  var id = ctx.createImageData(1, 1); // only do this once per page
  var d = id.data; // only do this once per page
  d[0] = r;
  d[1] = g;
  d[2] = b;
  d[3] = 255;
  ctx.putImageData(id, x, y);
}

let draw_line = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
  // Iterators, counters required by algorithm
  let x, y, dx, dy, dx1, dy1, px, py, xe, ye, i;
  // Calculate line deltas
  dx = x2 - x1;
  dy = y2 - y1;
  // Create a positive copy of deltas (makes iterating easier)
  dx1 = Math.abs(dx);
  dy1 = Math.abs(dy);
  // Calculate error intervals for both axis
  px = 2 * dy1 - dx1;
  py = 2 * dx1 - dy1;
  // The line is X-axis dominant
  if (dy1 <= dx1) {
    // Line is drawn left to right
    if (dx >= 0) {
      x = x1;
      y = y1;
      xe = x2;
    } else { // Line is drawn right to left (swap ends)
      x = x2;
      y = y2;
      xe = x1;
    }
    pixel(x, y); // Draw first pixel
    // Rasterize the line
    for (i = 0; x < xe; i++) {
      x = x + 1;
      // Deal with octants...
      if (px < 0) {
        px = px + 2 * dy1;
      } else {
        if ((dx < 0 && dy < 0) || (dx > 0 && dy > 0)) {
          y = y + 1;
        } else {
          y = y - 1;
        }
        px = px + 2 * (dy1 - dx1);
      }
      // Draw pixel from line span at
      // currently rasterized position
      pixel(x, y);
    }
  } else { // The line is Y-axis dominant
    // Line is drawn bottom to top
    if (dy >= 0) {
      x = x1;
      y = y1;
      ye = y2;
    } else { // Line is drawn top to bottom
      x = x2;
      y = y2;
      ye = y1;
    }
    pixel(x, y); // Draw first pixel
    // Rasterize the line
    for (i = 0; y < ye; i++) {
      y = y + 1;
      // Deal with octants...
      if (py <= 0) {
        py = py + 2 * dx1;
      } else {
        if ((dx < 0 && dy < 0) || (dx > 0 && dy > 0)) {
          x = x + 1;
        } else {
          x = x - 1;
        }
        py = py + 2 * (dx1 - dy1);
      }
      // Draw pixel from line span at
      // currently rasterized position
      pixel(x, y);
    }
  }
}


for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  draw_line(0, 0, 50, 100)
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```